# Вывод текста в TextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, text, controls

Есть переменная, которая получает значение вычисляемое методом при поступлении новых данных с потока. Как сделать программное изменение текста в textbox при присваивании новый значений переменной. Программное - это значит без участия пользователя, нажатия кнопок и т.д. Не таймером же проверять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для вашего класса реализуете интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Он необходим для оповещения о том, что изменилось значение свойства. Подробнее о нем можно прочесть в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Тогда всякий раз, когда будет изменяется ваше свойство, интерфейс будет обновляться и отображать актуальные данные.

Если вам нужно только выводить информацию, то лучше использовать `TextBlock` вместо `TextBox`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding НазваниеCвойства}" ... />
```

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged - я так понимаю - это позволит избежать прямого обращения к объекту из другого класса? На первое время решил проверить работает ли вообще метод синхронизации. Сделал так: `MainWindow fs = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow; fs.artist.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
            {
                fs.artist.Content = TagInfo.artist;
            }));` Знаю, что руки бы мне оторвать за такое, за то знаю, что работает. Обязательно перепишу как вы посоветовали )) Спасибо!

Comment: @Максим, Вы имеете ввиду из другого потока? Да, это позволит выполнять _вычисления_ в другом потоке, а потом, когда результат будет получен вернуться в поток UI . Таким образом не будет непосредственной связи с элементами управления. На этом сайте, насколько успел понять, есть возможность получить ревью кода, так что вы можете создать новый вопрос и услышать мнение других участников сообщества. Если ответ вам подошел, то, полагаю, можно отметить его "зеленой галочкой".